# Programmatically define execution order of scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events

By programmatically adding scripts to a given game object, will these scripts execute in the order they were added? Will their events run in the order they were added?

```
void Awake ()
{
    gameObject.AddComponent("Script_1");
    gameObject.AddComponent("Script_2");
}
```

Comment: From my experience, it certainly SEEMS to execute in the order the scripts are attached to the GameObject. I've tried it several times and have used it for plenty of non-production scripts. However, since there is no official documentation, and the chance that things can change, I wouldn't bank on this working all the time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Short answer: No. But you can set [Script Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html) in the settings (menu: Edit > Project Settings > Script Execution Order) or change it from code:

```
// First you get the MonoScript of your MonoBehaviour
MonoScript monoScript = MonoScript.FromMonoBehaviour(yourMonoBehaviour);
 
// Getting the current execution order of that MonoScript
int currentExecutionOrder = MonoImporter.GetExecutionOrder(monoScript);
 
// Changing the MonoScript's execution order
MonoImporter.SetExecutionOrder(monoScript, x);
```

1. [Script Execution Order manipulation](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/script-execution-order-manipulation.130805/#post-1323087)
2. [Changing Unity Scripts Execution Order from Code](https://web.archive.org/web/20160814074224/http://squabpie.com:80/blog/2015/11/13/scripts-execution-order.html)
3. [Change a script's execution order dynamically (from script)](http://gamedevrant.blogspot.de/2013/07/unity3d-change-scripts-execution-order.html)

p.s. This answer was written a long time ago, before `DefaultExecutionOrder` existed. Unless you are writing some editor tool to manipulate the execution order, DefaultExecutionOrder attribute may be more simple/suitable solution.

Comment: And your 'yourMonoBehaviour' handle comes from where? You allocate a new one? This just returns null.

Comment: Typically you are doing such things from an Editor script, so you can cast your target to MonoBehaviour:
`MonoBehaviour yourMonoBehaviour = (MonoBehaviour)target;`


If you are not familiar with Editor scripting, take a look some tutorials, e.g. https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/editor-scripting

Comment: ic tnx. Also found '[DefaultExecutionOrder(100)]' to be a better solution for my case.

Answer (score 32):

you can use the attribute:

```
[DefaultExecutionOrder(100)]
public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour
{
}
```

Comment: Awesome! In case you're worried this isn't doing anything (as I was) because it doesn't show up in the Script Execution Order window, that's apparently by design: https://forum.unity.com/threads/undocumented-but-public-defaultexecutionorder-attribute.530618/#post-5560372

Answer (score 5):

Some of the assets I've seen in the store, for example Cinemachine, set the executionOrder property in the .meta file (for example, MyMonoBehavior.cs.meta). I've tested and this indeed works (for example, change it from 0 to 200 then right-click and Reimport). It seems that the meta files are preserved in the package, so if you are distributing your asset, putting your asset package in the store with meta should work (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetPackages.html).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867935/execution-order-within-the-update-loop-method-in-unity3d)

> By default, the Awake, OnEnable and Update functions of different scripts are called in the order the scripts are loaded (which is arbitrary). However, it is possible to modify this order using the Script Execution Order settings.

Reference to Execution Order Setting can be found [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html)

Comment: Right, but that doesn't answer my question which asks about non-arbitrary loading (non-random).  So, loading scripts programmatically via the awake, are they run in the order they are added and continue to run in that order?

Comment: I think that you cannot get any better answer than that. It is not defined in which order they are executed. Unless you modify the order using the Script Execution Order Settings. The execution order is not defined probably because unity is executing them with multiple threads. After finishing with previous function each thread probably just processes next function that is not yet started to process.

Comment: It seems at least the scripting side of Unity is heavily single threaded, instead of multithreaded. It would make startup scripts a lot harder to program.

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this within editor scripts. Add class which initialized on load and set the MonoScripts Order dynamically.

```
[InitializeOnLoad]
public class SetExecutionOrder{

    static SetExecutionOrder(){
        MonoScript[] scripts = (MonoScript[])Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(MonoScript));
        int order = -100;  //Set this to whatever order you want
        foreach(MonoScript script in scripts){
            if(script.GetClass() == typeof(MyMonoScriptType)){  //The type of the MonoScript who's order you want to change
                MonoImporter.SetExecutionOrder(script , order);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This will also show the script within the script execution order window.